# How do I preload all local images?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I noticed in my app that when I go through pages you can see the images loading in despite the fact that they are local. Is there a way to pre-load all images so it won't need to load during the page transitions anymore?

Comment: Is this happening in debug or release mode?

Comment: Debug mode, is it because of that?

Comment: Most likely. Sometimes the images are not even packaged in the .apk if you are using Android, but they are being served through the packager in the same manner as the JS code. Try to make a release version and check if the issue appears again.

Comment: Alright I will try that and return to this. Thanks.